# How to persist the filters added by "Filter Now"?

Tags: filtering, fiddler

In Fiddler you can:

Right click on a session
Select Filter Now
Show/hide domain/process
[image]

Once you've added filters, they show up below the list of sessions:

[image]

Now the question is:

1. How do I persist the filters across fiddler starts
2. Can I save these filters, name them, in tags perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was unsupported in the past, but with [v5.0.20194.41348](https://feedback.telerik.com/fiddler/1361371-save-load-filter-presents) the filters are now preserved out of the box.

To clear the preserved filters, right click on them in the gray area below.

Comment: how can I clear one of them / all of them?

Comment: found how to do it - right click on each one of them